# autocomplete="off" in WebForms Application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I am using the DevExpress components in a WebForms application.

There is an issue with callbacks, Invalid ViewState, when the browsers back and forward buttons are used.

[The fix](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T282172) of adding `autocomplete="off"` to the main form works.

So in my Master page my `form` now looks like:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```

My question is could this affect anything else in the application? Is there anything I should look out for?

Answer (score 0):

it will only be for what is contained within that form. It will not affect anything else. Keep in mind what browsers are supported:

"Definition and Usage
The autocomplete attribute specifies whether a form should have autocomplete on or off.

When autocomplete is on, the browser automatically complete values based on values that the user has entered before.

Tip: It is possible to have autocomplete "on" for the form, and "off" for specific input fields, or vice versa.

Browser Support
The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the attribute.

Attribute
autocomplete    Yes Yes 4.0 5.2 15.0
Differences Between HTML 4.01 and HTML5
The autocomplete attribute is new in HTML5.

Syntax

Attribute Values
Value   Description
on  Default. The browser will automatically complete values based on values that the user has entered before
off The user must enter a value into each field for every use. The browser does not automatically complete entries"

Referenced: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp